# Properties of row become null after update with Realm

Tags: android, realm, insert-update

I found a really weird behaviour inside my application. When I want to update a record some unsetted properties become null in my Realm database.

```
Penetration penetration = new Penetration();
penetration.setQrid(Integer.parseInt(qrid.getText().toString()));
penetration.setStatus(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
penetration.setHeight(height.getText().toString());
penetration.setWall(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
penetration.setPosition(position.getText().toString());
penetration.setSparing(sparingLengte.getText().toString() + "x" + sparingBreedte.getText().toString());
penetration.setDoorvoerSoort(doorvoerSoort.getText().toString());
penetration.setDoorvoer(doorvoerLengte.getText().toString() + "x" + doorvoerBreedte.getText().toString());
penetration.setEis(Integer.parseInt(spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString()));
penetration.setExplanation(explanation.getText().toString());
penetration.setSync(1);

Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(penetration);
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close();
```

In the previous code I set every property except for: id and location_id
These unsetted property become NULL in the database.

Is this normal behaviour? If so, why?

Comment: For a not-required field, set it to null which is the default value. I think it's a very common behaviour in many databases.

Comment: @Dalinaum That's the problem, it gets setted to null while I want the property to stay the value it was. However, I found the answer to the problem. I need to fetch the data from the model and update its values. Problem solved.

Comment: `I need to fetch the data from the model and update its values.` if it exists, yes. Realm would have no way of knowing that you're trying to set the value to `null` or if you're "not trying to set the value to anything".